# UX Design Software for Android web based application

Tags: android, html, macos, web-applications

I am beginner in designing user interface for web based mobile apps. Is there any software on Mac OS X that i can use to develop user interface of web based mobile apps easily without using too much of CSS or HTML5.

E.g I developed some pages using Microsoft PowerPoint for Mac. Since my app requires a lot of pictures any program with easy drag and drop features would do. Thanks!

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow nowadays (see item #5 on http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

For web based mobile apps you mean mobile app written with web technologies such html5 or css?

Because i don't think that drag-and-drop UI builder exist, apart from MIT App Inventor, but it will generate java code.

You can use a framework like http://phonegap.com/, but it will require html5, css and javascript.